# Can or could ? Which one is better?

Tags: grammar

can or could?

Which one should I choose in the examples below?

Example 1

A: We have been trying to find the worst car in this country.

B: Well, this is definitely the worst one that **can/could** be found.

Example 2

A: My car broke down again.

B: Again? Your car is definitely the worst car that **can/could** be found in this country.

I think both "can" and "could" fit in the first one while "could" fits better in the second, but I don't know why.

Can someone explain?

Comment: I don't see any difference; your two examples are very similar. "The worst that can be found" suggests that the speaker has actually been searching, while "that could be found" is hypothetical - "Suppose we were to search the country for the worst car, we would not be able to find one worse than this".

Comment: Interestingly,

A: Look at the fish I got from my father yesterday.
B: It’s huge! It's definitely the biggest fish that can be found in the lake. =>Here can sounds fine because people tend to actually look for big fish. 

A: Look at the fish I got from my father yesterday.
B: It’s small! It's definitely the smallest fish that can be found in the lake. =>Here, using could is better because people do not really look for smallest fish when they go fishing.

Do you agree with my analysis? @KateBunting

Comment: I don't find either very natural, because unless you were to drain the lake and measure the length of all the fish in it, there is no way to know for certain how big or small they all are. In real life people would probably say  "That must be the biggest fish in the lake!"